# With jQuery ajaxpager

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm having an issue using "ajaxPager jQuery UI Widget" plugin.

You can see my demo [Here](http://www.sjlarchitect.com/help/projects_en1.html)
(only tab 1 has content)

It works great moving forward (using next, last, or page number links) through the pager, but if you navigate to previous pages (using previous, first, or page number links) it The new page content below, before showing the new page content.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: the problem also occurs when you navigate forward

Comment: It only appears when moving forward for me if the content has once been previously loaded.

any suggestions?